# ajax deleting user name value after checking the avaiability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I have a code that will check if the user name is available in the database the code works fine but  I am looking for away to delete the user name value automatically if the user name is unavailable.

here is my checking availability code,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Name").change(function(){
      var username = $("#Name").val();
      var msg      = $("#msg");
      if(username.length > 2){
        $("#msg").html('Checking availability');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "check_availability.php",
          data: "Name="+ username,
          success: function(messagess){
            $("#msg").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
              if(messagess.indexOf('OK') > 0){
                $("#Name").removeClass("exists");
                $("#Name").addClass("avail");
                msg.html('the user name is available</font>');
              }else{
                $("#Name").removeClass("avail");
                $("#Name").addClass("exists");
                msg.html('the user name is already exists');
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  User Email:&nbsp;
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
  <span id="msg"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using `.ajaxComplete` is not necessary; the `success` callback will handle that as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after showing message that user name already exists clear field:

```
$("#Name").removeClass("avail");
$("#Name").addClass("exists");
msg.html('the user name is already exists');    
$("#Name").val('');
```

Comment: but it deletes the value even if the user name is available?